# Is it bad to use non-icon images in mipmap folders on Android Studio 1.1?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, android-resources

I've read a few other questions but still don't fully understand. For non-icon images, is it better to create drawable folders within drawable (-mdpi, -hdpi, etc.)? Why NOT put these in the mipmap folders which are already created?

Is this wrong?
     android:drawableRight="@mipmap/arrow_right"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AZD4.jpg

New to android and a simple explanation would be extremely helpful, thank you

Answer (score 0):

For the most part it's for launcher icons when building density specific APKs, i.e. when you build an APK for each density bucket (MDPI/HDPI/...etc). Since launchers such as Google Now Launcher uses the icon one bucket up, i.e. an MDPI device will use the launcher icon in the HDPI folder, there's need a way for an APK to be density specific when provider different density launcher icons, hence the mipmap folder for launchers.

Unless your app will have density specific builds, it doesn't really make much difference whether you put your image resources in */drawable* or */mipmap*.